# Magento Product Addtocart go to Checkout Page by skip Cart Page

Tags: product, checkout, shopping-cart

In Magento, 
when the AddtoCart button is clicked the product should go straight to checkout page instead of cart page, i dont need to add the product to cart page, is it possible?

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: Sander,i thought to add the product to cart programmatically and redirect to checkout page, but the not able to get the solution, and i don't know this is the correct method.

Comment: you can make a redirect on the cart page that forwards to the checkout. This is probably easier than adding products programatically

Comment: but i dont want to show up cart page

Comment: thats what the redirect is for. You can do this with an observer or by rewriting the controller of the cart

Comment: If you want you can add your final solution as an answer and accept it to close the question

Comment: yes sure sander. that's i did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then config file i have added events observer,

```
<config>
....
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <controller_action_postdispatch>
                <observers>
                    <controller_action_after>
                        <class>membership/observer</class>
                        <method>membershipControllerActionPostDispatch</method>
                    </controller_action_after>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_postdispatch>
            <add_to_cart_after>
                <observers>
                    <add_to_cart_after>
                        <class>membership/observer</class>
                        <method>membershipCheckout</method>
                    </add_to_cart_after>
                </observers>
            </add_to_cart_after>
        </events>
    </frontend>
.....    
</config>
```

and My Observer file,

```
class Att_Membership_Model_Observer
{
    public function membershipControllerActionPostDispatch($observer)
    {
        if($observer->getEvent()->getControllerAction()->getFullActionName() == 'checkout_cart_add')
        {
            Mage::dispatchEvent("add_to_cart_after", array('request' => $observer->getControllerAction()->getRequest()));
        }
    }
   public function membershipCheckout($observer)
   {
      if (!Mage::helper('customer')->isLoggedIn())
      {
         Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('checkout/onepage', array('_secure'=>true)));
      }
   }

}
```

this gives solution for me,
the addtocart go straight to checkout page.

Thanks @sander